# Input Accessory View On Keyboard for New Time Picker

Tags: ios, swift, date, uidatepicker, ios14

Is it possible to add an input accessory view to the number pad that acts as the input view for the new iOS 14 style of time picker? I want the time picker to remain inline, and I'm keeping it as the displayer of the time as well, so no UITextField is being fed.

There is a .inputAccessoryView variable for the new time picker, but it can't be overridden.

For example,

```
    let timePicker = UIDatePicker()
    timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    timePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline

    timePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar      // this doesn't work
```

Wondering if there may be a way to get around this, like possibly pinning a view to the keyboard manually, but can't figure out how to do this. Any thoughts/ideas/workarounds on this?